# Passing HTML from serverside to datatables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, datatable

I am changing my Datatables to load content from my Rails app. In one of the cells I have a big chunk of HTML, and since when using the server-side approach the cells are printed with Javascript, I would need to pass the HTML from Rails.

So, here is how it looks one of the cells with datatables **WITHOUT** server side fetching:

```
<td>
          <div class='order-actions-container'>
          <div class='order-action'>
            <%= link_to 'Show pages', admin_order_pages_path(order.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
          </div>
          <% if order.status.name == 'reviewed' %>
            <div class='order-action'>
              <%= form_tag(admin_order_set_completed_status_path(order), :method => 'patch' ) do %>
                <%= submit_tag 'Complete order', class: 'btn btn-success', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to complete this order?' } %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          <% end %>

          <% if order.status.name == 'queued' %>
            <div class='order-action'>
              <%= form_tag(admin_order_process_order_path(order), :method => 'post' ) do %>
                <%= submit_tag 'Process order', class: 'btn btn-success', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to process this order?' } %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          <% end %>

          <% if order.status.name != 'processing' %>
            <div class='order-action'>
              <%= form_tag(admin_order_path(order), :method => 'delete' ) do %>
                <%= submit_tag 'Delete order', class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this order?' } %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          </div>
        </td>
```

Now, since all the data will come back from Rails, I would need to pass that HTML via a JSON. Isn't that breaking the MVC? How do you deal in these situations?

Comment: you can drastically clean up your form_tag & submit_tag code using the link_to helper method. ex <%= link_to "Complete order",admin_order_set_completed_status_path(order), :method => :patch, class: 'btn btn-success', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to complete this order?' } %> instead of wrapping it inside of a form tag. Rails will generate a form with this specific action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to use json with ajax for datatables you can use JBuilder or rabl to create a json document that can be easily reused.

Also there is not a need to write out form_tags wrapped around submit_tags to call different methods, with rails you can use link_to and specify the :method to accomplish the same thing.

```
<td>
  <div class='order-actions-container'>
  <div class='order-action'>
    <%= link_to 'Show pages', admin_order_pages_path(order), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>

  <% if order.status.name == 'reviewed' %>
    <div class='order-action'>
      <%= link_to "Complete order", admin_order_set_completed_status_path(order), method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-success', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to complete this order?' }%>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if order.status.name == 'queued' %>
    <div class='order-action'>
      <%= link_to "Process order", admin_order_process_order_path(order), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-success', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to process this order?' }%>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if order.status.name != 'processing' %>
    <div class='order-action'>
      <%= link_to "Delete order", admin_order_path(order), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this order?' }%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: The problem is how do you do the HTML part from the controller? I mean, datatables expects a JSON to render the table, so if in one of the cells there is HTML inside, you need to pass it from the controller. Isn't that breaking MVC?

Comment: Well in rails that's why the respond_to block works, you can use the same controller action and have it render HTML for initial, json for when a json request is made. Why do you feel it breaks mvc?

Comment: Because I am creating HTML code from the controller and passing it to the view inside of a JSON. Whereas I would say that in the JSON it should be just data.

Comment: You could write it that way but you would need to probably match the url on the button and change the path that each one is posting too, that would be more work, but would be 'pure' json.